# RequireJS: apply plugin to module id dynamically

Tags: javascript, requirejs, babeljs

I'm using the [requirejs-babel](https://github.com/mikach/requirejs-babel) plugin which requires prepending `'es6!'` to all module ids that need babel transpilation.

```js
define(['es6!some-es6-module'], function(module) {
  // ...
});
```

Is there an API in RequireJS that would allow me to inspect a module id and prepend the plugin id as-needed? For example, if I wanted to apply `'es6!'` to all module ids in a specific directory?

Ultimately I need to be able to write defines like this `define(['some-es6-module'], ...)` and automatically add the `es6!` prefix depending on what the module id is.

- Not looking for information on SystemJS or gulp tasks that do the transpilation ahead of time, etc.
- The exact module ids are not known at configuration time- I just know in certain locations/directories, modules will need `es6!`.
- Needs to work in the browser, at runtime

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to write a define like this, and have require automatically add the es6! prefix?  `define(['your-es6-module'], function(module) {...`

Comment: right- I'll update the question to make that more clear

Comment: You could always add your own hook right inside the `define` function in requireJs source....but then you'd have to defend it when it causes questions later or gets lost in an upgrade.  There's an issue (https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/issues/812) that talks about a similar hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overriding the `load` method.  The override uses the standard load for modules with mapped paths, otherwise it uses the `es6` (requirejs-babel) plugin to load the module.

```js
require.standardLoad = require.load;
require.load = function(context, moduleName, url) {
  var config = requirejs.s.contexts._.config;
  if (moduleName in config.paths) {
    return require.standardLoad(context, moduleName, url);
  }
  require(['es6'], function(es6) {
    es6.load(
      moduleName,
      require,
      {
        fromText: function(text) {
          require.exec(text);
          context.completeLoad(moduleName);
        }
      },
      {});
  });
};
```

Here it is in action: https://gist.run/?id=7542e061bc940cde506b

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure on your overall objective (do you want the es6 addition to module ID saved permanently or always auto-added?), but you may be able to use [RequireJS mapping](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) to substitute module ID's for defined modules. For example: -

```
requirejs.config({
    map: {
        // * - for all modules that require these, do this
        '*': {
            'some-es6-module': 'es6!some-es6-module'
        }
    }
});
```

However, considering your use-case you may need something more complicated than this, as mapping assumes you have actual different versions of files and is generally used for this purpose.

A more complicated solution I assume you are looking to avoid could be to dynamically loop your files before optimising them in r.js and loading/editing them via Node. It would get a little messy!

```
var config = requirejs.s.contexts._.config;
var needBabel = ['some-es6-module', 'another-module-name', 'another'];

for (var property in config.paths) {
    if (config.paths.hasOwnProperty(property) && needBabel.indexOf(property) > -1) {
        // load the module in node
        // fs.readFileSync(__dirname + config.paths[property] + '.js');
        // dynamically modify this file with text replacement
        // save this file via Node again
    }
}

// run Require JS optimiser

// undo everything you've just done when optimisation is complete
```